# Workaround for Broken Authorize.Net Sandbox Account Creation?

Tags: sandbox, amazon-cloudfront, authorize.net

Q:  Anyone know any working method, or alternate URL, to create an Authorize.Net Sandbox Account?

After filling out the Sandbox Account form at, https://developer.authorize.net/hello_world/sandbox/ , I received the error message:

```
URL: https://developer.authorize.net/hello_world/sandbox/

Complete Page Body:

    ERROR
    The request could not be satisfied.
    This distribution is not configured to allow the HTTP request method that was used for this request. The distribution supports only cachable requests.

    Generated by cloudfront (CloudFront)
    Request ID: eA28WPE73_KAV2p91ixOhETSVWssiFeOdvnr0az40wxLVIT2bDBhBw==

    ==EOF==
```

Edit 2017-12-04:

While not an answer to my question (which may be “There is none.”), I ‘mis’-used Authorize.Net’s contact form to request a manual account creation.  As opposed to the ~2 days they give for reply ETA, the above form was ‘fixed’ and they replied, “I just tested the page and I could not recreate the error” within ~5 hours.

I’ll leave the question open for a week in case someone knows an answer, and afterwards close it with ‘None.’

Comment: You should be contacting Authorize.Net about this

Comment: Authorize.Net’s support page requests you use Stack for support...

Comment: For support with *coding* questions. This isn't a coding question. This belongs in [their community forums](http://community.developer.authorize.net/)

Comment: John :)  If their forms are broken, how could someone create an account in their forums to ask said questions?  Issue is closed, see "Edit 2017-12-04".  Best

Comment: Their community forums seem to work just fine. But I'm glad it got sorted out.